# Is there a XOR style or multi type lock in C#?

Tags: c#, locking

I need a lock that implements exclusion in a different way than usual. Instead of a Reader Writer lock, I need a multi type lock.

So everyone of type A can join, everyone of type B can join, but not A and B together.

If this doesn't exist, how can I implement it in a simple and elegant way?

Comment: Usually `lock(object)` is used to give exclusive access to a resource. What do you mean by "join"?

Comment: `So everyone of type A can join, everyone of type B can join, but not A and B together.` Please explain to us what `everyone` is, `type A` is, `type B` is and **why** you want to do this.

Comment: So when you say lock, lets make sure we are talking the same language, do you mean memory barriers or fencing, or just process flow exclusion. ? do you have a problem reading and writing to a shared resource atomically ? or are you just trying to guarantee high-level order of process

Comment: Anything really. The point is the lock has the following API: lock.RequestLockTypeA and lock.RequestLockTypeB. Everyone who does one method can run concurrently with the same type, but not with the other type. That's why I called it a XOR lock. Either one or another type, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for exclusion and you are not needing to ensure instruction order and specific read write memory barriers. Then I give the worlds most convoluted example.

Basically it's just an encapsulated way of queueing up async workloads via a `TaskCompletionSource` to run exclusively by *type*. It's fairly light-weight, it will work well with the thread pool and work for multiple types.

**Given the classes**

```
public class Base
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bob:Base { }
public class Cat:Base { }
public class Flib:Base { }
```

**Some sort of workload**

```
public static async Task SharedAsync<T>(T instance) 
   where T : Base 
{
   await _xor.WaitAsync(instance);
   try
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Starting " + typeof(T) + " " + instance.Id);
      await Task.Delay(100);
   }
   finally
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Fishing " + typeof(T) + " " + instance.Id);
      _xor.Release(instance); 
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
_xor = new XorLimiter(typeof(Bob), typeof(Cat), typeof(Flib));

static Task Generate(int x)
   => _r.Next(0, 3) switch
   {
      0 => SharedAsync(new Bob() {Id = x}),
      1 => SharedAsync(new Cat() {Id = x}),
      2 => SharedAsync(new Flib() {Id = x}),
      _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   };

var tasks = Enumerable
   .Range(0, 15)
   .Select(Generate);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```

**Output**

```
Starting Program+Bob 0
Starting Program+Bob 3
Starting Program+Bob 7
Starting Program+Bob 8
Starting Program+Bob 9
Starting Program+Bob 14
Fishing Program+Bob 9
Fishing Program+Bob 7
Fishing Program+Bob 8
Fishing Program+Bob 14
Fishing Program+Bob 3
Fishing Program+Bob 0
Starting Program+Flib 1
Starting Program+Flib 2
Starting Program+Flib 5
Starting Program+Flib 10
Fishing Program+Flib 10
Fishing Program+Flib 5
Fishing Program+Flib 1
Fishing Program+Flib 2
Starting Program+Cat 4
Starting Program+Cat 6
Starting Program+Cat 11
Starting Program+Cat 12
Starting Program+Cat 13
Fishing Program+Cat 12
Fishing Program+Cat 13
Fishing Program+Cat 6
Fishing Program+Cat 11
Fishing Program+Cat 4
Finished
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dv66uq)

---

**XorLimiter Class**

```
public class XorLimiter
{
   private readonly Type[] _types;

   private readonly object _sync = new object();
   private Type _current;
   private readonly Queue<Type> _next = new Queue<Type>();
   private readonly Dictionary<object, int> _processing = new Dictionary<object, int>();
   private readonly Dictionary<Type,List<(object instance, TaskCompletionSource<bool> source)>> _waiting = new Dictionary<Type, List<(object instance, TaskCompletionSource<bool> source)>>();

   public XorLimiter(params Type[] types) => _types = types;

   private void Process()
   {

      if (_processing.Any() || !_next.Any()) return;
      _current = _next.Dequeue();

      if(!_waiting.TryGetValue(_current,out var list))
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Nothing to process");

      foreach (var (instance, source) in list)
      {
         AddOrUpdate(instance);
         source.TrySetResult(true);
      }

      _waiting.Remove(_current);
   }

   public void Release<T>(T instance)
   {

      if(!_types.Contains(typeof(T)))
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Not monitoring type : " + typeof(T).Namespace);

      lock (_sync)
      {
         try
         {
            if (!_processing.ContainsKey(instance))
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Instance does not exists");

            _processing[instance]--;

            if (_processing[instance] < 0)
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Instance count is less than 0");

            if (_processing[instance] == 0)
               _processing.Remove(instance);

         }
         finally
         {
            Process();
         }
      }
   }

   private void AddOrUpdate<T>(T instance)
   {
      if (_processing.ContainsKey(instance))
         _processing[instance]++;
      else
         _processing.Add(instance,1);
   }
   public ValueTask WaitAsync<T>(T instance)
   {

      if(!_types.Contains(typeof(T)))
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Not monitoring type : " + typeof(T).Namespace);

      lock (_sync)
      {
         try
         {

            _current ??= typeof(T);

            if (_current ==typeof(T))
            {
               AddOrUpdate(instance);
               return new ValueTask();
            }

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            if (!_waiting.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var list))
            {
    
               _waiting.Add(typeof(T), list = new List<(object instance, TaskCompletionSource<bool> source)>());
               _next.Enqueue(typeof(T));

            }
            list.Add((instance,tcs));
            return new ValueTask(tcs.Task);

         }
         finally
         {
            Process();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

<sub>***Note**: This is nothing but a trivial example of how you might attack such a problem. There are many many other approaches, and this is not meant to be peer reviewed code or the bastion of perfect or lock-free code. This has only been tested minimally and lacks a lot of fault tolerance, and basic functionality like cancelation tokens and sanctity checking.*</sub>